# find corresponding text from subtitle

Tags: javascript, data-structures, subtitle

I have text file (subtitle) like this format:

> each row has starting time and ending time of the text

```
45.123 : 55.002 = this_is_subtitle_of_video
58.101 : 64.022 = next_text_and_so_on 
...
...
458.101 : 564.022 = final_text_of_video
```

from youtube API I can get current time(seconds) like this 123.06 (sec)

> How can I get corresponding text when I have current time of the video (maybe using array or
>   another data structure)...

algorithm should work fast (when video is playing on the site)

Comment: english-club.uz   ---> using simple array it works with small videos (like music-clips). I want to use with long-videos...

Answer (score 0):

You could [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text at each `\n` and loop through each line. Then use the regex

```
/(\d+.\d+) : (\d+.\d+) = (.*)/
```

and [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to put the start and end times and the subtitle to separate capturing groups

```js
function findSubtitle(text, time) {
  let lines = str.split("\n");

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    [,start, finish, subtitle] = lines[i].match(/(\d+.\d+) : (\d+.\d+) = (.*)/);
    if (time >= start && finish >= time) {
      return subtitle
    }
  }
}

let str = `45.123 : 55.002 = this_is_subtitle_of_video
58.101 : 64.022 = next_text_and_so_on 
458.101 : 564.022 = final_text_of_video`

console.log(findSubtitle(str, 60.006))
console.log(findSubtitle(str, 48))
```

If you want to find subtitles repeatedly from this text, you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of subtitles. Whenever you need to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) a subtitle, call the function with the array and the time. This way you don't have to `split` and `match` every time you want a subtitle

```js
function findSubtitle(array, time) {
  let inner = array.find(a => time >= a[0] && a[1] >= time) || [];
  return inner[2];
}

let str = `45.123 : 55.002 = this_is_subtitle_of_video
58.101 : 64.022 = next_text_and_so_on 
458.101 : 564.022 = final_text_of_video`

let subArray = str.split("\n")
                  .map(a => a.match(/(\d+.\d+) : (\d+.\d+) = (.*)/).slice(1))

console.log(findSubtitle(subArray, 60))
console.log(findSubtitle(subArray, 48))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that it already works using simple array with small videos, hence you could simply replace your array with a Map.

(see. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)